# Hide status bar on button tap Swift 3 / iOS 10

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uibutton

I cannot seem to be able to hide the status bar in my root view controller (A) when a button is pressed.

I have set the properties in my info.plist `Status bar is initially hidden` and `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`.

If I implement the `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { get }`, the status bar will be definitively hidden (or not).

**What I need**

I want the status bar to be displayed in (A) but hidden when I press a button that adds a child view controller to (A).

I have tried setting `prefersStatusBarHidden` to `false` and hide it using `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true` when the button is pressed but this does not work.

There must be something I am getting wrong, could anyone enlighten me ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I merely need it to be invisible, not necessarily "hidden" in the Swift sense.

Answer (score 12):

To hide the status bar

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
```

To bring back the status bar

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal
```

Comment: works with Swift 3. 
`UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden` is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to hold a boolean to set if the status bar is hidden or not

```
var _isStatusBarHidden: Bool = false
```

Then create its getter and setter

```
var isStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get{
        return _isStatusBarHidden
    }
    set {
        if _isStatusBarHidden != newValue {
            _isStatusBarHidden = newValue
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

You must override the `prefersStatusBarHidden` property

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return self._isStatusBarHidden
}
```

Last thing is to set the variable to `true` when the user presses the button:

```
self.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little improvement of @Alexandre Lara `s code:

```
var isStatusBarHidden: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != self.isStatusBarHidden {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return self.isStatusBarHidden
}
```